# Can I find the start address of "free" memory when using emscripten to compile to WebAssembly?

Tags: webassembly, emscripten

So, I have a C application that e.g., takes a string:

```
void EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE modify_entity(char* target) { ... }
```

In order to interact with this, I need to put the target somewhere into the WebAssembly memory. Essentially, my Embedder would create the string in the format that the C code expects (in this case, a null-terminated ASCII string) and put it into the WebAssembly memory, and then pass a pointer to that memory address into the function.

But: How do I know where in memory to put this?

If I look at the .wat file, I see that emscripten adds several data sections:

```
  ...
  (data $d10 (i32.const 1619) "\14")
  (data $d11 (i32.const 1631) "\17\00\00\00\00\17\00\00\00\00\09\14\00\00\00\00\00\14\00\00\14")
  (data $d12 (i32.const 1677) "\16")
  ...
```

My understanding is that these data segments exist in the same memory (the single `(export "memory" (memory $memory))`) since at the moment, WebAssembly implementations only support a single memory. So if I was to write into memory at address 1619, I'd overwrite the stuff from the data section, which would be bad.

Is that correct? And if that is correct, is there some way for an Embedder to find a valid memory address of free memory? I can manually check the .wat file and find the first free memory, but I wonder if there's a variable or function?

The only thing that looks somewhat promising is a global: `(global $g0 (mut i32) (i32.const 67456))`. But that global seems to be used throughout the generated WebAssembly code, so I'm not sure if I should use that as a free memory pointer.

Or would I have to somehow expose a malloc/free function from WebAssembly? I know there are quite a few implementations I could use, but I was hoping that the Embedder could handle all that itself, because all I need is to find some free memory that's safe to use. Is that possible, or is that a folly because I'd be competing with whatever internal memory allocation happens on the C side?

Comment: wasm itself has no "malloc" type function. it has the equivalent of sbrk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options:

1. As suggested already you could export and call the `_malloc` C function.
2. Even easier you could call `stringToNewUTF(my_js_string)` which will return  you a pointer to `_malloc`'d memory containing your string.
3. Even better you could call `stringToUTF8OnStack` which avoids the allocator and returns a stack address pointing to the encoded string.
4. Even even better you can use `ccall` or `cwrap` to do all this for you .e.g. `ccall('modify_entity', null, ['string'],[my_js_string]);`  See https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/Interacting-with-code.html#interacting-with-code-ccall-cwrap

Comment: Thanks, I should've added that I'm not embedding it from JavaScript, so I have to do my own marshalling, but I can definitely look at how emscripten implements those JavaScript functions and just port them.

Comment: To add: When using `-O3`, it seems like Emscripten might optimize away malloc/free from the exports. So adding `-s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS="['_malloc', '_free']"` to emcc arguments, I'll get proper exported functions for malloc/free exported from the module. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you should just make passthrough functions for malloc/free.

also, its recommended to pass a string pointer and a length but its wasm so its containerized anyway. if you want to pass a null terminated string thats fine.

[also make sure your js string is actually a char*](https://dev.to/mistval/beware-of-emoji-in-js-144o)

or if you want the hacky solution:
grow the wasm memory and place your string in the new page (only if you can guarantee your function will not call malloc)

your question in essence "find me a place to put my string" is just asking for a memory allocation.

[here is the proposal for multiple memories](https://github.com/WebAssembly/multi-memory) yes there is currently only one memory.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not embedding it into JavaScript, but good call out on making sure the string encoding is correct (I'm manually writing bytes, so I know it is, but it's definitely a concern when passing strings back and forth to Wasm)